# get h5p interactive quiz result

Tags: drupal, tin-can-api

I had make a interactive quiz with module h5p on Drupal 7. Now, I would like to know how I can get the user's result ? I found that I can use TinCan API to do that but I cannot find any guide on internet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if by "I found that" you mean the [official documentation](https://h5p.org/documentation/for-authors/analyzing-results-and-answers).

The steps basically are

1. [Install TinCan Bridge](https://www.drupal.org/project/h5p_tincan_bridge) for Drupal
2. [Install Learning Locker](https://learninglocker.net/) on a Server or get an account hosted somewhere
3. Configure TinCan Bridge by entering the endpoint for Learning Locker and your credentials

Alternatively, you can install [Drupal Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) ans the H5P questions add on that will provide reports about H5P content types.